# Debug .net maui app for Android in vscode

Tags: vscode-debugger

i need to test my app developed with .net maui in VisualStudioCode.
and i need to do it with an android emulator recently installed from command line (i can use other ways if someone explain me)
please someone can help me?
Tanks.

I not find something online